# Как сделать адаптивный фон чтобы при меньших разрешениях был на всю ширину?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть вот такой хедер с адаптивным фоном:

```
header {
    background: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #464646;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Но при уменьшении разрешения нужно чтобы картинка была во всю ширину и высоту. То есть не часть её, а полностью. Как это сделать? Если что, верстаю по сетке бутстрапа.

Comment: background-size:cover;
Пропорции правда не будут сохранятся. 

А если с сохранением пропорций
background-size:contain;

а вообще, читай
https://webref.ru/css/background-size

Comment: Что - бы background-size:cover масштабировал фоновую картинку, высота блока так-же должна изменяться.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 1):

Если ты используешь картинку как фон в `header` используй:

```
header{
  background:url(path_to_your_image) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/NikitaSmith/uz2n1r3p/4/

Если ты хочешь использовать картину внутри блока,чтобы она была адаптивной:
HTML:

```
<img src="path/to/your/image" alt="">
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/NikitaSmith/gzy4yngh/2/